# On the formulation of a sufficient condition for integrability of a function

Tags: integration

I'm using a common book for Calc III, and am struggling with the author's words for a sufficient condition for integrability of a function $\textit{f}$ over a set $\textit{B}\subset R^{3}$.Be aware,there's also a version of this theorem for $R^{2}$, same problem. It is stated as follows:

Let $B\subset R^{3}$ be bounded and $f: B\mapsto R^{3}$ be bounded $\textbf{and continuous}$. Under these conditions, if the boundary of $B$ has content zero, then $f$ is integrable in $B$.

The "continuous" bugs me. Why is it there? I understand $f$ being bounded does not characterize a sufficient condition for integrability, but continuity does. If it is continuous, then it's automatically integrable. He uses the fact that $f$ is continuous to construct a function $g$ over a "block" $A$ that contains $B$, and defines $g(x,y)=f(x,y)$,when $(x,y,z)\in R^{3}$, and $g(x,y)=0$ whenever $(x,y,z)\notin B$. The argument makes sense, and it's solid, but since from the beginning $f$ is continuous, why did we even go there? Wouldn't it make more sense if the theorem were

Let $B\subset R^{3}$ and $f: B\mapsto R^{3}$ be bounded. Under these conditions, if the boundary of $B$ has content zero, then $f$ is integrable in $B$.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: "If it is continuous, then it's automatically integrable" - but we still have to prove it. Without continuity the statement is simply not true - $f$ can be bounded but not integrable.

Comment: I know we have to prove that if $f$ is continuous then it's integrable, have no issues with that. My particular issue is how this was structured, the fact that continuity of $f$ has been guaranteed makes it unnecessary to prove the integrability of $f$ based on the other assumptions. We can just say "continuous $\Rightarrow$integrable",no?

Comment: This depends on details on how exactly integration over arbitrary set is defined. Can you please either cite the definition or refer source?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now,  but I'll leave it here. He defines double integrals on page 75, and triple integrals on page 173. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b8LR7AXYc5uq7C05OfGMEG8rNQ9PD-9Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is that you're being too hasty when you declare "if it is continuous, then it is automatically integrable." This theorem surely was stated/proved when the domain is a rectangle.

Comment: Oh,okay. Yes, the theorem was proven into a rectangle $A$ that contains the domain $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without either continuity or zero content, $f$ don't have to be integrable over $B$.

Let $B = [0, 1]^3$ and $$f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}1,& x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ isn't integrable over $B$, as for any partition the integral sum can be $0$ and can be $1$.

For the other case, let $B = ([0, 1] \cap \mathbb Q)^3$ - rational points in unit cube, and $f(B) = 1$. Then again for any partition in any element we can find a point where $f$ is $1$, and we can find a point not in $B$, so corresponding term in integral sum will be $0$.

So again, for any partition the integral sum can be $0$ or $1$, and so $f$ isn't integrable.